# Vertically align images in old browsers

Tags: html, css

I'm using the following gallery plugin on a website. http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/example-2.html

Notice that images vertically align to the middle. The div containing images has a vertical align property and line height set to the dimension of the div's height. Unfortunately images don't align to the middle in older browsers like AOL..

What css can I use to make alignment happen?

Comment: Old browsers like AOL???

Comment: I say that because AOL still seems old despite the upgrades.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many techniques to make vertical centering happen, with various levels of compatability. The first two Google results give some good techniques:

- [Understanding vertical-align, or "How (Not) to Vertically Center Content"](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:ljidO1EwAAYJ:phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a)
- [Vertical centering using CSS](http://www.student.oulu.fi/~laurirai/www/css/middle/)

One that might work well for you is the absolute positioning technique. It depends on you knowing the image height exactly, but for an image gallery you probably will be displaying all images at the same height. Essentially:

```
.img-container {
    position: relative;
}

.img-container img {
    height: 400px;      /* up to you what the correct height is */
    margin-top: -200px; /* put here 1/2 of the image height from above */
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}
```

for markup something like

```
<div class="img-container">
    <img src="whatever.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: I think using absolute position has serious drawbacks when considering different screen resolutions.

Comment: Thanks that's a good solution but suppose I don't know the height of images.

Comment: In that case you can't do it with CSS for older browsers, as the links I gave show in their browser compatibility tables. You'll need JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question well then I think I am afraid to say that it cannot be achieved with CSS only. In that case you may need to calculate the width and height of the container div which holds the image and then divide it by two to locate the center and place your image there.
`margin: 0 auto;` will align this horizontally and not vertically.

Note: It will be purely jquery.

Comment: Are you confusing jQuery and JavaScript?

Comment: No, I am actually promoting jquery. off course both will work

Comment: http://www.doxdesk.com/updates/2009.html#u20091116-zalgo and especially http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif are relevant in that case.

Comment: goshhh!!, I cant believe that, 22 upvotes and accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could force height on image to specific size, position image absolutely to relative container at top: 50% with a margin-top -(50% of height)px. That would be a pure css solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your best technique for vertically-aligning is to use the `vertical-align` CSS attribute:

```
<div id="thumbs">
    <!--Thumbnails for images-->
</div><div id="gallery">
    <!--Images-->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#thumbs {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block; }
#gallery {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block; }
#gallery img { display: block; }
```

Preview: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/PHrw5/

Comment: Vertical align is already set and does not work in awful browsers like AOL. I'm looking for a fullproof solution. I think that js is key as others mentioned..

Comment: Vertical align only works for table cells